# Framework7 and Android: Icons render in browser but not on device

Tags: android, html, cordova, font-awesome, html-framework-7

When I use framework7-icons on the web, they render just fine, but when I launch my project on my Galaxy S8, the name of the icon is displayed instead of the actual icon.

On the web:
[image]

On my Galaxy S8:
[image]

My code:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="left"><i class="f7-icons size-28">menu</i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before copying build folder to cordova, in build/static/Css folder, open the css files and search for  **src:url(/static/media/MaterialIcons-Regular.e79bfd88.eot)** and replace it with **src:url(../media/MaterialIcons-Regular.e79bfd88.eot)**. This will work for sure.